# return id AUTO_INCREMENT value in mysql DB immediately after insert

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

hi ther I use this mysqli code to insert in DB.

mail DB has an id AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mail (".$sqlname.") VALUES (".$sqlValue.")";
        if (!($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)) 
        {
            echo 'false';
            return false;
        }
        else
             return $id; // return id of insereted record in table
```

Is there any way to return id in mail table realtime after insert?

I can call last ID by call another function....But it may gone wrong for high traffick insert to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysqli, you can do it with [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
return $conn->insert_id;
```

If you are using PDO, you can do it with [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

```
return $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Description:

When a new AUTO_INCREMENT value has been generated, you can also obtain it by executing a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement with mysql_query() and retrieving the value from the result set returned by the statement.

For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.

See detail here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: thanks for the great answer.